# Why printing new line character takes long time?

Tags: c++, output, newline

I am solving some problem and was testing with sample test case which prints 2*10<sup>6</sup> integers.

On initial run, I used `cout<<ans;` and it took `0.602s`for giving output.

I realized that I wasn't printing each output in a new line. So changed it to `cout<<ans<<endl;`. This time it took `2.052s`!

Why does just printing a new line character after each line takes so long time?

Comment: Because it causes flushing: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29701830/1938163

Comment: Flushing is by far the primary issue.  A much smaller secondary effect, which is not covered in the other question, is that, depending on your platform, a "newline" may not be as simple as just another character.  On some platforms it may be multiple characters.  On a record-oriented filesystem, it might be an update to an on-disk data structure that contains the length of the line you just ended.