# what is the diffrence between std::cout<< x ; and std::cout<<x<<std::endl;?

Tags: c++

I'm a newbie to programming, I started teaching myself yesterday, I've been getting everything but I honestly, do not understand the difference between

```
std::cout << x;
```

and

```
std::cout << x << std::endl;
```

Nobody has explained this to me, and I'm asking to stay on the safe side.

Comment: For [further reading](http://stackoverflow.com/q/213907/5583153)

Comment: [This answer of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29701830/1938163) might also help understanding potential implications

Answer (score 12):

`endl` writes a new-line to the stream, so subsequent output will appear on the next line. It also flushes the stream's buffer, usually [causing a slow-down](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1926432/179910).

This flushing means that 99% of the time, `endl` is a mistake, and you should just write `"\n"` (or `'\n'`) instead. When you really do want to flush the stream, I think it's better to make that explicit by invoking `std::flush` instead:

```
std::cout << x << '\n' << std::flush;
```

As far as run-time actions goes, this is equivalent to using `std::endl`, but in terms of making your intent clear, it's *drastically* superior.

Comment: Just an observation that might help some readers: if you want to output some manner of prompt, such as `std::cout << "type your name:";`, you don't (by default) need to use `endl` or `flush` before attempting input from `std::cin`, as they're "tied" streams and take care of that automatically.

Answer (score 0):

The `std::endl` adds a newline code to a stream and also flushes the output buffer and `std::cout << x` is just printing `x`.
So if you got a code

```
cout << 5;
cout << 5;
```

it will be

> 55

as an output, but if you add a `endl` to a first `cout` the output will be

> 5
>
> 5

What i really recommend you is to use `'\n'` it is much more better than endl.

Comment: "i really recommend you is to use '\n' it is much more better than endl"
Better for what? Performance? And what else?

Comment: It's good when I get it for free. If it can introduce other problems, I'd rather avoid it. Though to be honest, I'm personally using a wrapper around `printf` for logging instead of streams