# what is the significance of these lines

Tags: io, inputstream, c++14, user-input

I found in this [code](http://codeforces.com/contest/743/submission/22981724) on codeforces . I am not that expert please guide me the use of these lines of code 
The question just reads an input string of integers of maximum length 1000

```
ios_base::sync_with_stdio(0), cin.tie(0), cout.tie(0);
#ifndef ONLINE_JUDGE  
freopen("test.in", "r", stdin); 
#endif
```

Comment: Which part, exactly, do you not understand?

Comment: Sir, I did not understand the first four lines  I have shown in highlighting the four lines.It would be great if you would help :)

Comment: That's not specific enough. Where should we start? With the origins of the lowercase letter i? C++ syntax? Or the subtleties of IO buffering? Tell us what you understand and which parts, specifically, you don't.

Answer (score 0):

The first line is basically done to speedup reading files since these features are not generally required in competitive coding (take this with a grain of salt):

1. Usage of `ios_base::sync_with_stdio` can be found in [Using scanf() in C++ programs is faster than using cin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1042110/using-scanf-in-c-programs-is-faster-than-using-cin)
2. Usage of `cin.tie(0), cout.tie(0)` can be found in [Why do we need to tie std::cin and std::cout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14052627/why-do-we-need-to-tie-cin-and-cout)

As for using `ONLINE_JUDGE` it has been explained in codeforces [blog](http://codeforces.com/blog/entry/14118). Basically, when codeforces runs the code online it adds the `ONLINE_JUDGE` flag. In your case if you are running the code at home you can ignore `ONLINE_JUDGE` flag and it will read your test file `test.in`. The same code while running in Codeforces will have `ONLINE_JUDGE` set and will ignore the `freopen("test.in", "r", stdin);` line and run its own test cases.